# How to select a rows which has the word 'Toronto ' from this data set?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how do I select rows which contain the word 'Toronto' from this dataset:
I need to have data frame which has the only the details of 'Toronto'
[image]

Comment: Please post what you have tried :)

Comment: And please don't post pictures, paste your data in the question

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for asking someone to do your assignment, Post a real technical question with, what you want, what you had and how, else this is not the place. Remove also the picture please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. There is a lot missing from your question so let me know if I am off base.

```py
df[df['column name'].str.contains('Toronto')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `str.contains` for this:

```
df = df[df['city'].str.contains('Toronto')]
```